# In MYSQL, Can we do the Looping using Normal SELECT SQL rather than using Stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, loops

ok, Her is my problem. I got a table that has 3 columns: C1, C2, C3

```
C1 - C2 - C3
 M - is - M1
N2 - is - N3
M2 - is - M3
M3 - is - M4
N1 - is - N2
M1 - is - M2
 N - is - N1
```

So when user search for "M1", the system will show:

```
M1
M2
M3
M4
```

when user search for "M3", the system will show:

```
M3
M4
```

when user search for "N", the system will show:

```
N
N1
N2
N3
```

Clearly, this kind of query requires some sort of looping, ie searching for any word after "is", then continuously searching for word after that word.

I wanna use normal "Select SQL" in MySQL rather than using Stored Procedure to do this task. But I have no clue how to do.

Do we have to use "WITH" keyword?

How to do the above query without using Stored Procedure?

Comment: A term to search for is "transitive closure". See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_closure#In_database_query_languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, sticking to the requirement of NOT using a stored procedure, the following query may be used:

```
SELECT t1.C1 AS Value1, t2.C1 AS Value2, t3.C1 AS Value3, t4.C1 AS Value4
FROM your_table t1
LEFT JOIN your_table t2 ON t1.C3=t2.C1
LEFT JOIN your_table t3 ON t2.C3=t3.C1
LEFT JOIN your_table t4 ON t3.C3=t4.C1
```

It will return results such as `M1 M2 M3 M4`. If you need to "loop" more, you may add another `LEFT JOIN` to the query:

```
SELECT t1.C1 AS Value1, t2.C1 AS Value2, t3.C1 AS Value3, t4.C1 AS Value4, t5.C1 AS Value5
FROM your_table t1
LEFT JOIN your_table t2 ON t1.C3=t2.C1
LEFT JOIN your_table t3 ON t2.C3=t3.C1
LEFT JOIN your_table t4 ON t3.C3=t4.C1
LEFT JOIN your_table t5 ON t4.C3=t5.C1
```

[You will however be limited in the number of tables you can join this way](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/joins-limits.html):

> The maximum number of tables that can be referenced in a single join
>   is 61.

You will need to use server-side language (PHP?) to check if Value2, Value3...ValueN are null or not.

My advice is to use a stored procedure, or to change your table schema to avoid having to loop in your tables this way.

Comment: Thax you Jocelyn very much.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* accomplish this task using a recursive CTE; unfortunately, mysql does not yet support these.

However, I submit to you that you have a larger problem in that you're implementing the classic SQL Antipattern referred to as a "Naive Tree"; I strongly recommend you review the slidedeck [SQL Anti-Patterns Strike Back](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back) - especially the section beginning around slide 48, where the author will provide viable alternatives that will make your problem easier to encapsulate in the subset of SQL your database supports.